# JPA : Implicit find by composite primary key

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key

Please I'm trying to find Quiz by Audit (using spring data jpa) and there must be an implicit search for the quizSubCategory which has a composite key, here are the classes :

**Quiz entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quiz")
public class Quiz {
@EmbeddedId
private QuizCK id;

@Column
private String title;

@Column
private String status;

@Column
private String state;

@Column(name = "start_date")
private Date startDate;

@Column(name = "end_date")
private Date endDate;

@Column
private String reference;

@Column
private String results;

@Column(name = "is_default")
private boolean isDefault;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_audit")
private Audit audit;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_quiz_sub_category", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_language", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private QuizSubCategory quizSubCategory;

@MapsId("idLanguage")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_language", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Language language;

public Quiz() {


}

// constructor & getters & setters
}
```

**QuizSubCategory entity:**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "quiz_sub_category")
public class QuizSubCategory implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private QuizSubCategoryCK id;

private String libelle;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_quiz_category", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_language", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private QuizCategory quizCategory;

@MapsId("idLanguage")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_language", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Language language;

public QuizSubCategory() {
    super();
}

//constructor & getters & setters
}
```

**QuizSubCategoryCK (primary key):**

```
@Embeddable
public class QuizSubCategoryCK implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "id_quiz_sub_category", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idQuizSubCategory;

@Column(name = "id_language", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int idLanguage;

public QuizSubCategoryCK() {
}


public int getIdQuizSubCategory() {
    return idQuizSubCategory;
}

public void setIdQuizSubCategory(int idQuizSubCategory) {
    this.idQuizSubCategory = idQuizSubCategory;
}

public int getIdLanguage() {
    return idLanguage;
}

public void setIdLanguage(int idLanguage) {
    this.idLanguage = idLanguage;
}
}
```

**QuizRepository :**

```
public interface QuizRepository extends JpaRepository<Quiz,QuizCK> {
List<Quiz> findByAuditAndLanguage(Audit audit, Language language);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/quizzes/{auditId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<QuizBean> listQuizzes(@PathVariable int auditId){
    AuditBean auditBean = auditService.getAudit(auditId);
    LanguageBean languageBean = languageService.getLanguageById(1);
    List<QuizBean> quizzes = quizService.findByAudit(AuditMapper.fromBean(auditBean),LanguageMapper.fromBean(languageBean));
    return quizzes;
}
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Unable to find jpa.entity.QuizSubCategory with id jpa.entity.QuizSubCategoryCK@79a59c48; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find jpa.entity.QuizSubCategory with id jpa.entity.QuizSubCategoryCK@79a59c48
```

Any hints please ?!

Comment: Can you provide more code? Are you using JPARepository? Give us a code where you try to fetch from DB.

Comment: @ByeBye I've updated my post, yep JPA Repository

Comment: Is entities are poperly mapped? You have @OneToMany relationship between QuizSubCategory and Quiz but you dont use Collection

Comment: It's a ManytoOne relationship, why do I need a collection ! ?

Comment: Because one Quiz has many SubQuizes - many SubQuizes, not one SubQuiz. Am I wrong?

Comment: it's a quizSubCategory not subQuizes, I don't have subQuizes !

Comment: How you provide audit and language in:

List<Quiz> findByAuditAndLanguage(Audit audit, Language language); ?

Comment: @ByeBye I added my controller